# apache nifi PrometheusReportingTask: server returned HTTP status 500 Server Error

Tags: apache-nifi, prometheus

I have setup nifi(1.10) PrometheusReportingTask [nifi setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq0wn.png) with port 9192 and other default properties.
and in Prometheus in the same machine, setup the *prometheus.yml* as

```
  - job_name: 'nifi'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9192']
```

however, after restarting Prometheus , Prometheus can't get the metrics from nifi with 500 error:
[500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPhSd.png)

Could someone advise why and the solution?  Ｉ can't find more detail in the apache nifi doc.

Comment: Is your Prometheus on the same machine running on the same port? If so that will cause a problem, the PrometheusReportingTask opens the specified port so it can be scraped. Check that your Prometheus is not using port 9192, or else your config says you'll be scraping your own Prometheus and not NiFi's (which will fail when it tries to open the same port).

Comment: prometheus is running with port 9091

Answer (score 2):

Checked that it is caused by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6902 which will be fixed in nifi v1.11